# Advanced Installer - How to add a custom launch condition to check if a specific software is installed or not while installing

Tags: visual-studio, installation, advanced-installer, launch-condition

I am have C# project for which i have created a installer by using [advanced installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/) the installer build perfectly but now i have some preferences to check while installing my software that is a specific software is installed on the machine or not.
I have seen there are launch condition tab in the advanced installer
[image]

In the launch condition i can see there are prebuild conditions available. how can i add my custom condition in the custom tab to detect a specific software installation

[image]

[image]

i dont figured out how to add my own custom condition here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please note that the "Not Installed" condition you are refering to in your thread refers to the installation state of the main setup package.

Now, coming back to your issue, please that if the software you are looking for is a common one, you can use the **"Launch Conditions"** --> **"Software"** tab.

If the software you are looking for is not found there, then we must find a trait that is specific to your software (e.g. a file, a registry entry).

We can then create a "Search" based on that trait and use the property assigned to the search as a condition to our custom Launch Condition.

https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/search.html

For instance, if we know that the software we are looking for always creates a registry entry upon installation, we can perform a registry search:

https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-registry-search.html

and then use the property that stores the value of the search as a custom launch condition.

One more thing to note here is the behavior of the Launch Condition:

- if the condition is evaluated as true ==> the setup will continue
- if the condition is evaluated as false ==> the setup will abort and the Launch Condition Description will be displayed to the user

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @CMk it really helps. I just have to switch to professional version of advanced installer and i am able to see the custom options on the left bar as explained in your answer